# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea Not working the same on Vista

Tags: vb.net, winforms, aero-glass, dwm

Ive been using the class Glass_full from here:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/146813-glass-form-dwmapidll-api/

It works fine on Windows 7. Ive even managed to find a easy workaround for the text issue.
I solved this by using a custom color for backcolor and transparencyKey on the form (Color is rgb 1,2,3)
This works fine on 7 but when the same code is ran on Vista it doesnt render the glass.

I can render the glass with backcolor black, and transparencyKey works to make the form completely transparent, but when combined like i did on 7, the glass doesnt render. (I get rgb 1,2,3 for a background)

I tried adding a propertyGrid to a form and using it to set the backcolor and transparencyKeys   for testing but DWM would crash when i set transparencykey to the same as backcolor.

Is there any way of fixing this?